# Where to find ESP32's api's commit changes?

Tags: github, commit, esp32

Recently I've started using ESP32 for a bluetooth application, and so I've searched tutorials for nimble communications. The problem is, some of the functions used in said tutorials are no longer used in newer version of ESP-IDF.

In various threads, people link espressif's gitHub containing the commit from when a function gets replaced in the api. However,I get somewhat lost when trying to find specific commits.
Would really appreciate if someone could teach me how to search more efficiently for api changes between ESP-IDF updates.

Comment: If you view the commit history for header files only, that would likely narrow in on API changes

Comment: If someone has provided you a link to a Github commit, or source file, generally you can use the "Blame" (git blame) feature to see who changed that particular line, when, and why. Also, I don't know about ESP, but generally if there's developer documentation available, it will be versioned and you can find the last version that function existed and usually a deprecation notice. Not all projects are the same however.

Comment: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v5.0.3/esp32/api-reference/index.html - here you can change the ESP target and api version. I would walk yourself backwards through versions and locate the last version that contained that particular API call you are referencing, and then see if there's a deprecation notice, or an alternative available.